# Small avatars for ignored chat users break chat's "people in room" display

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, profile-picture, ignored-users

In chat, the avatars of active and inactive users in each room are displayed in rows at the top right of the window. When users are ignored, their avatars get shrunk to 1/4 size, providing an easy indication that they're present, but, you know, not really. (This is a great design, by the way. +1 @team.)

However, the reduced-size avatar leads to a bug in positioning of other avatars when it's at the end of a row. Screenshots will illustrate it best. Here's normal alignment:

[image: screenshot of normally aligned avatars]

And here's misalignment:

[image: screenshot of misaligned avatars]

The only (relevant) difference is that the user with the circular avatar is set to "ignored" in the second screenshot.

And to answer the inevitable question: no, I don't have that user ignored "for real." It's just to demonstrate the bug. I chose him because his avatar was at the end of the row when I was ready to take the screenshot, and it's easy to pick put a circle among a bunch of squares.

EDIT:
After further experimentation, I've found that:

- The space to the right of a mini-avatar is still clickable, like the avatar itself, but the space below it is not
- Ignored users still show up in the main site sidebar widget thing (this is [not a bug](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/321026#321026); just documenting)
- Starred messages from ignored users show up in the sidebar list even if they @-mention the user doing the ignoring (this is almost certainly also not a bug)

EDIT 2:
It seems that if ignored users leave a room for long enough to drop out of the "users in room" list and later come back, their avatars in the "people in room" list return to full size.

EDIT 3:
Looks like ignoring multiple users can cause all sorts of alignment weirdness. Maybe this is actually by design.

[image: screenshot with several users ignored]

Comment: "the user with the circular avatar". So that's how it's going to be. I notice you have a circular avatar too -- prepare to be IGNORED

Comment: @Michael, you're going to ignore me? And, therefore, not be able to reply to me or interact with me in any way? Oh thank god, _finally_.

Comment: Hmm.... OK; good spot...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can now safely ignore Michael Mrozek without having to fear for the sanity of the layout, and even when he leaves and re-enters, he will stay small.