# Ignoring somebody screws up the avatar list

Tags: bug, chat, ignored-users

When I ignore a user, the avatar list looks weird.

[image]

The blank line beneath the row with the avatar of the ignoree is quite annoying.

---

I use Google Chrome on OS X.

There was a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71653/small-avatars-for-ignored-chat-users-break-chats-people-in-room-display) tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) but it still looks weird.

Comment: Same with FF on WinXP and Win7.

Comment: Same with Chrome on Win7.

Comment: Confirmed, CSS rule still missing in April 2015.

Comment: @JasonC what a surprise.

Comment: And still missing four years later... and will most likely still be missing in 40 years.

Answer (score 19):

The missing CSS rule is:

```
#present-users > .present-user.ignored {
    height: 16px;
}
```

The following userscript adds the rule to all chat rooms:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name SE ignored chat user fix
// @description Add missing CSS rule to Stack Exchange chat rooms to fix display of ignored users
// @version 1.0
// @author DaveRandom
// @namespace https://github.com/DaveRandom
// @match http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/*
// @match http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*
// @match http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

    var s = document.createElement('style');
    s.appendChild(document.createTextNode('#present-users > .present-user.ignored { height: 16px; }'));
    document.head.appendChild(s);

}());
```

Although obviously just adding the missing rule to the Stack Exchange stylesheets would be better :-P

Comment: Thanks! I've incorporated you fix into a collection of small user script fixes that I'm calling the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Comment: The link `http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*` should be changed to `http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/*` due to MSO/MSE splitting, but since it's already incorporated in SOUP, I don't think it really matters...