# Avatars of ignored users cause extra row spacing below them in "people in room" display

Tags: bug, chat, ignored-users

A similar, but more severe, issue was reported back in 2010 and marked as completed: [Small avatars for ignored chat users break chat's "people in room" display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71653/small-avatars-for-ignored-chat-users-break-chats-people-in-room-display). A milder issue currently exists.

When a user is ignored and their small avatar is displayed in the "people in room" avatar grid, extra whitespace appears immediately below the row the avatar is in.

Normal spacing:

[image]

First row:

[image]

Second row:

[image]

Third row:

[image]

Changing the width of the browser window has no effect.

Chrome 41, Windows 7.